How can I add a cloudy environment without adding more lights?
I have this scene I am making, currently its with a world, fogs and some lights to create the scene. However, I want to create a mildly cloudy night sky. Like how would expect at a stormy sea? I couldn't find any night time HDRI, so I just been trying by turning the HDRI black and white. It kinda works? But far from good.
Main issue though, is that any HDRI I add, introduces more light to the scene which I do not want. Any suggestions?

